# winsound.Beep(440, 1000) не работает

Tags: python

Пытаюсь написать `winsound.Beep(440, 1000)`, вылезает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    winsound.Beep(440, 1000)
RuntimeError: Failed to beep
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: [Если система не может подать звуковой сигнал на динамик, возникает ошибка RuntimeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html#winsound.Beep)

Comment: А почему не может и как разрешить?